# EditorFor and ApplyFormatInEditMode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations, editorfor

I'm working with MVC 5, and I'm having an issue formating decimal numbers

I have a decimal with 18,5 precision in my model and I want to show it for editing with `EditorFor` but it is ignoring the `DataFormatString` even though `ApplyFormatInEditMode` is `true`

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Example{ get; set; }
```

Using the number `4` as example

if I render it as:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Example) //result: 4 (this is what i want!)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Example) //result: 4.00000
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Example) //result: 4.00000
```

how can I work with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Example)` will be 4, not 4.00000 when using the in-built default templates, therefore I can only assume that you must have a custom `EditorTemplate` defined for typeof `decimal?` (check the `EditorTemplates` folder in `/Views/Shared` and `Views/YourControllerName` folder for a file named `Decimal.cshtml`).

The result you see when using `TextBoxFor()` is correct. The `[DisplatFormat]` attribute is only respected when using `DisplayFor()` or `EditorFor()`. To format a value using `TextBoxFor()`, you need to use an overload that accepts a format string

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Example, "{0:#.#####}") // result: 4
```

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly my problem!